# How to schedule a job in pl/sql?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I have created one stored procedure with name

```
traffic_details_temp_send_mail;
```

How to make this procedure to run everyday at 10AM?

Please help with block of code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can create a scheduler job:

```
begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name        => 'TRAFFIC_DETAILS_JOB',
                              job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                              job_action      => 'traffic_details_temp_send_mail',
                              start_date      => systimestamp,
                              end_date        => null,
                              repeat_interval => 'freq=daily; byhour=10; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
                              enabled         => true,
                              auto_drop       => false,
                              comments        => 'your description here.');
end;
/
```

then you can see the details in the scheduler job views (user_scheduler_jobs etc). see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm) for information on scehduler jobs.

Comment: Dazzal. What is the difference in DBMS job scheduling and DBA job scheduling

Comment: @Shreedhar `dbms_job` is the older job scheduler with not as good logging and scheduling capabilities. i'd use scheduler if i were you for any new jobs you want (also Oracle's recommendation is that you don't use `dbms_job` aanymore..but its still supported)

Comment: @Shreedhar One difference is that dbms_scheduler performs a commit when adding a job, where dbms_job does not. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4153606/121544