# How Can We Delete A Table Row Automatically After a Specific Time in PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have Tow table with Identical Columns Given Below:

Table-1 PAYROLLFILE:

[image]

Table-2 TEMP_PAYROLLFILE:

[image]

I have written a PL SQL Function, which inserts a duplicate row from Table PAYROLLFILE to TEMP_PAYROLLFILE and remove the original row from Table PAYROLLFILE.So in short, Table TEMP_PAYROLLFILE is keeping a backup for deleted data from  Table PAYROLLFILE.

Here is the PL SQL Function Code:

```
FUNCTION Remove_transaction_by_id(employee_id NUMBER)
RETURN CLOB
AS
  cnt INT;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO temp_payrollfile
    SELECT *
    FROM   payrollfile
    WHERE  empid = employee_id;

    DELETE FROM payrollfile
    WHERE  empid = employee_id;

    SELECT Count(*)
    INTO   cnt
    FROM   payrollfile;

    COMMIT;

    RETURN '<result><status>success</status> <row>'
           ||cnt
           || '</row></result>';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
             RETURN '<result><status>Error</status></result>';
END remove_transaction_by_id;
```

However, I want to do more than that, **I want to Delete Backup rows Automatically** from Table TEMP_PAYROLLFILE **after a specific time period is over** fort that **specific row**.Do i need triggers.I am new on that and never done this type of work before.If anyone know this kind of technique, then i would really appreciate your help.please let me know if further details required.Thanks

Updates:

I have write this job to cleanup old rows: will it work?

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'oe.REMOVE_TEMP_PAYROLLFILE_JOB',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           => 'BEGIN DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('oe',
                            'TEMP_PAYROLLFILE'); 
                            delete from TEMP_PAYROLLFILE where RECORDDATE < sysdate-1;
                            END;',
   start_date           => '20-JAN-16 1.00.00AM US/Pacific',
   repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY', 
   end_date             => '25-JAN-16 1.00.00AM US/Pacific',
   enabled              =>  TRUE,
   comments             => 'Gather table statistics');
END;
```

Comment: you can execute a stored procedure periodically to delete unwanted rows (with times greater than given period)

Comment: Thanks @Kilanny  for the 1st response to this post.However I have never done  stored procedure **periodically to delete unwanted rows**.If you know something code then please help.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**What you need here is a periodic cleanup job.** Using [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm) you can configure a job that does this repeatedly:

```
delete from TEMP_PAYROLLFILE where recorddate < sysdate-60;
```

to delete records that are more than 60 days old.

[These](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm) are some examples on how to create a scheduled job. As you see below, the job_action sections accepts a Pl/SQL script, in which you can place your cleanup logic.

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name             => 'oe.my_job1',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           => 'BEGIN DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(''oe'',
                            ''sales''); END;',
   start_date           => '15-JUL-08 1.00.00AM US/Pacific',
   repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=DAILY', 
   end_date             => '15-SEP-08 1.00.00AM US/Pacific',
   enabled              =>  TRUE,
   comments             => 'Gather table statistics');
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks @Gergely Bacso.Very helpful info.where should i write this code,in my existing function or need to write another. can you show me a little bit.Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384952/how-to-schedule-a-job-in-pl-sql check this for scheduling the job

Comment: @user5005768, I added some extra info.

Comment: Thanks @Gergely Bacso. can you please tell me where i have to put that code you mentioned [ delete from TEMP_PAYROLLFILE where recorddate < sysdate-60; ] inside my pl sql function or  inside scheduler job_action ? Thanks

Comment: The job_action takes pl/sql as parameter. So wrap your cleanup SQL into a `BEGIN ... END;`, then put into the job_action field.

Comment: Thanks @Gergely Bacso. are you suggesting this edit. job_action=> 'BEGIN DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(''oe'',
                            ''TEMP_PAYROLLFILE'');  delete from TEMP_PAYROLLFILE where recorddate < sysdate-60; END;'

Comment: Thanks @Gergely Bacso.re you suggesting this edit.  job_action=> 'BEGIN DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(''oe'', ''TEMP_PAYROLLFILE''); delete from TEMP_PAYROLLFILE where recorddate < sysdate-60; END;'

Comment: Do you want to gather table_stats? No. Then don't. That was just an example. I can't believe that you wrote that Pl/sql script above and now suddenly you are unable to follow this. I gave up. I am sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Create a stored procedure to perform the deletion:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE remove_Temp_Transacts_by_ID(
  in_employee_id IN NUMBER,
  in_datetime    IN TIMESTAMP
)
AS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM temp_payrollfile
  WHERE  empid     = in_employee_id
  AND    datetime <= in_datetime;
END;
/
```

Then in your function include a call to schedule a job to run the procedure at a later time:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
  JOB_NAME   => 'Remove_TTbID__JOB',
  JOB_TYPE   => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
  JOB_ACTION => 'remove_Temp_Transacts_by_ID'
  START_DATE => ( SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '2' HOURS ),
  ENABLED    => FALSE,
  COMMENT    => 'One time job to remove temporary payroll file entries'
);

DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(
  JOB_NAME   => 'Remove_TTbID__JOB',
  ARGUMENT_POSITION => 1,
  ARGUMENT_VALUE    => employee_id
);

DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(
  JOB_NAME   => 'Remove_TTbID__JOB',
  ARGUMENT_POSITION => 2,
  ARGUMENT_VALUE    => SYSTIMESTAMP
);

DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE( 'Remove_TTbID__JOB' );
```