# How to create dbms job that runs on weekdays(Mon-Fri) at 5:30 AM

Tags: oracle, plsql, jobs, dbms-job

I want to create dbms job using **DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT** package that runs on weekdays(Mon-Fri) at 5:30 AM. I am not sure what values should be passed in next_Day and interval Can anyone please help?

Comment: use dbms_scheduler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152111/dbms-job-vs-dbms-scheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to create one user defined function as following :-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DATE RETURN DATE
is 

V_DAY VARCHAR2(10);
V_DATE DATE;

BEGIN

SELECT (to_char(sysdate,'fmDay')) INTO V_DAY FROM DUAL;

IF(V_DAY='Monday' OR V_DAY='Tuesday' OR V_DAY='Wednesday' OR V_DAY='Thursday') THEN


SELECT trunc(sysdate+1)+05/24+30/1440 INTO V_DATE FROM DUAL;
RETURN V_DATE;

ELSE

SELECT trunc(sysdate+3)+05/24+30/1440 INTO V_DATE FROM DUAL;
RETURN V_DATE;

END IF;

END;
/
```

After that we need to create job in the following way :-

```
DECLARE
  XYZ NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT
  ( job       => XYZ 
   ,what      => 'BEGIN PROC_NAME; END;'
   ,next_date => to_date('23/03/2017 05:30:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
   ,interval  => 'GET_DATE'
   ,no_parse  => FALSE
  );

END;
/
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [dbms_schedular](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235) package, which is available since 10g, you can use 'repeat_interval' parameter as follows:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
            job_name => 'MY_JOB',
            job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
            job_action => 'your code',
            number_of_arguments => 0,
            start_date => NULL,
            repeat_interval => 'FREQ=WEEKLY;BYTIME=053000;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI',
            end_date => NULL,
            enabled => FALSE,
            auto_drop => FALSE,
            comments => '');

END;
/
```

Furthermore, if you are using an IDE such as [SQL Developer](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/scheduling-jobs-with-oracle-sql-developer/), you can easily set the details of your job without worrying about the syntax. In fact, the code above is generated by SQL Developer

**UPDATE**
Try the following using dbms_job (not tested)

```
DECLARE
   l_job_number NUMBER;
BEGIN
   dbms_job.submit( 
          job       => l_job_number ,
          what      => 'your code',
          next_date => trunc(sysdate)+05/24+30/1440,
          interval  => CASE WHEN (to_char(sysdate,'Day') IN ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')) THEN trunc(sysdate)+05/24+30/1440 else null end 
          );
END;
/
```

Comment: I want it to create it through dbms_job package because as of now i am not having rights to execute dbms_scheduler package. Can you please help?

Comment: it's showing an error near " ); " (where the job ends). Just a question - do we need to end the case?

Comment: interval  => CASE WHEN (to_char(sysdate,'Day') IN ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')) THEN '' END

  --What should be the proper value instead of '' after THEN. This statement does not show any syntax error.

Comment: @user7349009 Yes, there should be `then ... end` I corrected that

Comment: It must be 'fmday' otherwise the text is padded with space character

Comment: The job gets executed successfully but does not run on specified time i.e. 5:30?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit 
 

Can you please help on this?

Comment: @Hawk - Can you please relook on this?

Comment: You must use `CASE WHEN (to_char(sysdate,'fmDay') IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')) THEN ...` or even better `CASE WHEN (to_char(sysdate,'fmDay', 'nls_date_language = english') IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')) THEN ...`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - It's throwing an ORA-06512 error at line 'Case when.........then...'

Comment: DECLARE
  X NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT
  ( job       => X 
   ,what      => 'BEGIN  schema_name.proc_name; END;'
   ,next_date => to_date('22/02/2017 05:30:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
   ,interval  => CASE WHEN (to_char(sysdate,'fmDay') IN('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')) THEN trunc(sysdate)+05/24+30/1440 else null end
   ,no_parse  => FALSE
  );
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job Number is: ' || to_char(x));
COMMIT;
END;
/

Comment: I tried several ways but none of them worked. Seems to be not possible - go for `DBMS_SCHEDULER` as suggested in answer (and as recommended by Oracle [DBMS_JOB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_job.htm#ARPLS66558) ).

Comment: There should be something for dbms_job too... As i said before i currently don't have access to dbms_scheduler.